# Using additional template type parameters as type alias declarations to use in function's signature

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, stdarray

Given a function template whose signature contains a lengthy name at multiple locations, e.g. a function template taking two `std::array`s containing themselves size-3 `std::array`s and also returning one,

```cpp
// Clumsy - requires multiple line breaks
template <typename T, std::size_t n>
typename std::array<std::array<T, 3>, n> 
foo(const typename std::array<std::array<T, 3>, n>& points_a, 
    const typename std::array<std::array<T, 3>, n>& points_b)
{
    typename std::array<std::array<T, 3>, n> result;
    // .. process ..   
    return result;
}
```

would it be unwise to **introduce additional, redundant template type parameters with derived default values in order to use those type parameters' names to make the function's signature more legible**? In the example's case `typename Points = typename std::array<std::array<T, 3>, n>` would be added to the template parameters:

```cpp
// Better
template <typename T, std::size_t n, typename Points = typename std::array<std::array<T, 3>, n>>
Points bar(const Points& points, const Points& offsets)
{
    Points result;
    // .. process ..   
    return result;
}
```

To prevent misusage of the additional template type parameter (which shall obviously not be used by clients at all) the function might apply a compile-time check to verify that its instantiation led to the parameter's default type being used (via `if constexpr (std::is_same<...>())`).

The whole point of this question is to reduce code duplication in a function template's signature (when the duplication does reduce legibility). This method appears natural to me but I am unsure about whether any problems might arise which I am unable to see.

Thank you.

Comment: So first, surely `typename` before `std::array` here isn't necessary? Removing it would declutter your declaration. Second, if `std::array<T, 3>` is an abstraction of a point, I'd suggest type aliasing, further decluttering your declaration: `template <typename T> using Point = std::array<T, 3>;`. The same could be done with the outer `std::array` if you in your context find that it makes sense. And while you could use compile time checking for the third template argument it strikes me as a bit of a code smell. In situations like this I usually step back and see if anything can be abstracted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see problems with your additional-typename solution (except the risk, that you have just seen, of the type explicated).

But I propose a completely different solution: make `foo()` receiving a generic typename `AA` (for Array-Array)

```
template <typename AA>
AA foo (AA const & points_a, AA const & points_b)
```

and, if you need they, inside the function you can extract the internal type (the old `T`) in a `using`

```
using T = typename AA::value_type::value_type;
```

and, using the specialization of `std::tuple_size` for arrays, also the external dimension (the old `n`)

```
static constexpr auto n { std::tuple_size<AA>::value };
```

If you also want impose that the internal `std::array` is of size 3, you can do it through SFINAE (using a `std::enable_if_t` for the returned type) or through a `static_assert()` inside the function

```
static_assert( std::tuple_size<typename AA::value_type>::value == 3u );
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <array>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template <typename AA>
AA foo (AA const & points_a, AA const & points_b)
 {
   using T = typename AA::value_type::value_type;

   static constexpr auto n { std::tuple_size<AA>::value };

   static_assert( std::tuple_size<typename AA::value_type>::value == 3u );

   std::cout << std::is_same<T, int>::value << ' ' << n << std::endl;

   AA result;

   // .. process ..   

   return result;
 }

int main ()
 {
   std::array<std::array<int, 3u>, 5u>  a;
   std::array<std::array<long, 3u>, 7u>  b;
   std::array<std::array<long, 5u>, 9u>  c;

   foo(a, a); // print 1 5
   foo(b, b); // print 0 7
   // foo(c, c); // compilation error

 }
```